# scatter plot with empty circle within loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I am looking for a simple and elegant way to make a scatter plot with multiple arrays, using empty circle as marker The colours should be chosen automatically.
For example, I can make a plot with filled circle very easily:

```
a = {'1': np.random.rand(10), '2': np.random.rand(10), '3': np.random.rand(10)}
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for y in ['2', '3']:
    ax.scatter(a[y], a['1'], label=y)
```

IF I want to use the kwargs `facecolor="none"`, the markers just disappear. Somehow I need to automatically assign colors to `edgecolor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the edge color manually via `C0`, `C1`, etc., which follow the default palette:

```
a = {'1': np.random.rand(10), '2': np.random.rand(10), '3': np.random.rand(10)}
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for i, y in enumerate(['2', '3']):
    ax.scatter(a[y], a['1'], label=y, facecolor='none', edgecolor=f'C{i}')
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I access the default palette (f'C{i}')

Comment: @VinodKumar those colors work by default. You can control them e.g. with seaborn: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VinodKumar you are welcome! If this answer satisfies you, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Done that! StackOverflow allows me to accept the answer after a time delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use string `o` as a `marker`:

```py
a = {'1': np.random.rand(10), '2': np.random.rand(10), '3': np.random.rand(10)}
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for y in ['2', '3']:
    ax.scatter(a[y], a['1'], label=y, marker='$o$')
```

Comment: This is smart but only a way around. I have limited flexibility to choose markers in this way.

Comment: @VinodKumar Yeah I figured, but just wanted to give you another option =)